# Backbone Model set data for POST save

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I use Backbone.Associatons for my project.
This library modifies the toJSON method for Backbone.Model.
I also modified it myself for use with the template engine I use.

I now essentially have a large object of nested Backbone.Models (or JSON objects, after the toJSON call) and some additional properties.

When I edit a model and call the save() method with the patch:true option, I can provide data as a JSON object and only this data is sent to the server.

```
model.save(modelData, {patch: true});
```

However, when my model is new and Backbone does a POST request, it serializes the data of my model by calling toJSON, even though I provide a data object as the first argument for the save method.

Therefore, the data sent to the server is not accepted, because it has all those nested properties.

How can I make Backbone use a custom toJSON method when POSTing data or how can I make it use the data I provide in the first argument of the save method?

Answer (score 0):

maybe solution is not very nice, but you can move data, that is not going to be sent, to a temporary variable (if you need it later).

```
//...
// use silent if something is listening to `change` event
var silent = { silent: true };
var tmp = model.toJSON();
model
  .clear(silent) // remove everything from the model
  .save({ foo: 'bar' });  // send only required data

model
  .clear(silent)  // remove data that was sent
  .set(tmp, silent);  // set back initial data

//...
```

but there might be a conflict with data, that comes from response after save

Comment: I don't think this will think.
Since the toJSON method that adds and modifies model properties is still called in the save method like this, this would not solve the problem.
I'm looking for a way to override save() or sync() and provide a different toJSON method for saving.

Comment: `toJSON` actually uses data that is in the model, that's why i've added `clear` before `save`. or do you mean that your extended `toJSON` automatically adds additional properties to the result?

Comment: Exactly that. Backbone.Associations modifies the properties too when toJSON is called.